# before_create, before_destroy, after_save and other callbacks not getting called on join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason when a join table is created/destroyed in my ror app the callbacks aren't getting called.

```
class ImagesProducts < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = "images_products"

  self.primary_keys = :product_id, :image_id

  belongs_to :product, touch: true
  belongs_to :image, touch: true

  after_save { product.touch }

  def self.belonging_to(product_ids)
    belonging = where(product_id: product_ids)
    return belonging
  end

end
```

So apparently product.touch is not getting called here, I tried with logging as well, but none of the callback methods seem to actually be triggered when I create or destroy one of these records.

Are callbacks not working on join tables for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
  belongs_to :product, touch: true
```

and

```
  after_save { product.touch }
```

do the same thing. However touch won't be called on `create` so you might need to use an `after_create` callback:

```
after_create :touch_product

def touch_product
  self.product.touch
end
```

for update and destroy `belongs_to :product, touch: true` should be enough.

More on `touch` below this line:

---

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch

> Please note that no validation is performed and only the after_touch,
>   after_commit and after_rollback callbacks are executed.

Also as far as I understand the way `touch` works, is whenever you update/destroy a record, the one in relation will be `touch`ed and will only save the record with the updated_at/on attributes set to the current time, nothing more than this.

---

From **Active Record Callbacks**
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

> Additionally, an after_touch callback is triggered whenever an object
>   is touched.

so you can use this callback in product model to do whatever you need when an `image_product` will be destroyed/updated.

---

From **ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods** http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

> :touch If true, the associated object will be touched (the
>   updated_at/on attributes set to now) when this record is either saved
>   or destroyed. If you specify a symbol, that attribute will be updated
>   with the current time in addition to the updated_at/on attribute.

Comment: I'm doing this because it seems that touch: true isn't working here. When it gets created it doesn't appear to actually touch image or product. And after_create isn't called either. Could it be that my tables aren't actually using my models when being created?

Comment: @ChristianA.Strømmen join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67122/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-27523772-before-create-before-destroy-after-sa